# YUI3 Datatable Row Highlight/Link

Tags: jquery, css, yui3

Im using YUI3 Datatables to output data to a table, problem is im not sure how to make the rows highlight on hover / link to the corresponding account id. Normal CSS does not work as the class and names change depending on what data is in the table.

Ive tried to use normal CSS to target the `tr > td:hover` selector but it doesnt work and to be honest im lost.

I cant find any in-date solutions for this, just 3-4 year old, outdated answers.

as requested JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/s73aznvb/

Comment: Please provide your code and a fiddle

Comment: @dude it doesnt run at all i dont use jsfiddle much but either way the link is in the description

Comment: @MarkPerera not sure if youve used YUI3 Data Tables before or not but the table gets rendered so initially it doesnt display rows or cells

Comment: I thought you hadn't added `Yui` as it wasn't in external resources. Later only I saw you had added it in the html

Comment: Ah as i said before i dont use jsfiddle much so im not 100% how i should have added an external script

Answer (score 0):

This is just for anyone still looking for anything to do with the YUI3 Datatables documentation, I think it would be a better idea to ask on the YUI3 Forums which ive JUST discovered..

http://yuilibrary.com/forum-archive/forum/index.html?

The threads seem to be active and filled with useful information!